# I can't kill multiprocessing pool because the object reference doesnt exist any longer

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a python code and ran pool inside a class, the problem is that I made some mistakes and corrected the code but without killing pool by PoolObject.terminate() now I can't create a new multiprocessing using pool:

```
ValueError: Pool is still running
```

and to make it worse, as I rerun the code I lost the reference of previous pool to then kill it.

I tried to restart my computer,and the approach below

```
import subprocess

def terminate_pool_processes():
    # Get the list of running processes
    output = subprocess.check_output('tasklist', universal_newlines=True)

    # Find and terminate the pool processes
    for line in output.splitlines()[3:]:
        process_info = line.split()
        if 'python.exe' in process_info[0] and 'multiprocessing.pool' in process_info[0]:
            subprocess.run(['taskkill', '/F', '/PID', process_info[1]])

# Call the function to terminate all pool processes
terminate_pool_processes()
```

Comment: Are you saying that restarting your computer was not effective at resolving the error?  If so, that cannot possibly be a result of the original pool still running.  It is more likely a result of some kind of lock file still hanging around.  Or maybe your code is just buggy.

Comment: do you know where the follow warning is located in "Another instance is already running, quitting."? I'd like to modify the method by my own to ignore this exception

Comment: It seems unlikely that you can successfully *ignore* the issue.  If you genuinely cannot start any new pools (which seems more unlikely the more I think about it), you'll need to find and fix the system or user-account problem that is causing that.  If your pool-using program is just buggy then you'll need to debug that.  Possible debugging techniques include, but are not limited to, (i) running Python interactively to test various aspects of pool use; (ii) running your program under pdb or another Python debugger; (iii) breaking the program down to a [mre].

Comment: Each pool is local to a single interpreter. In no way does one interpreter stop another interpreter from creating a pool -- if it did you could only have one program or service using `multiprocessing` on each computer, and that would make no sense.

Comment: would reinstall python worth?

Comment: i dont have patience to debbug it, I dont even know how multiprocessing works, just like to apply in order to run a massive function one time ever life

Comment: Instead of showing us code you're trying to use (unsuccessfully) to _avoid_ the problem, how about showing us a [mre] built from the code you're using to _cause_ the problem? This isn't a problem anyone but you has; nobody else knows how to create it, then, _unless you show us what you're doing_ so we can work out why it's happening to you in the first place.